# AWS cognito and groups

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I am considering using Cognito and specifically groups for managing authorization.

Since there is a soft limit of 25 groups per account, I am questioning the real value of using groups, vs. just adding a custom role attribute and assigning roles that way in Cognito. The call to get AWS IAM creds from the identity pool would still work I believe as it looks at the role.   Is the main value of using groups then simply to make it easier to administer the user-role mappings through the console?

If so, it seems like it may be better to simply use custom attributes.

Comment: I would suggest to use Cognito for authentication and use your own implementation for authorization specifically for multitenant applications. If its a single tenant application and you can use a custom attribute to store the role. Other than that the group is basically a grouping to grant joint permission as you clearly understood. These permissions are more useful if your application accesses AWS resources.

Answer (score 0):

One of the benefits of using the default/native groups in Cognito is that AWS AppSync supports schema-defined permissions on a field level. This can be great for some usecases but if it’s not yours, it doesn’t matter. You can expect more services from AWS to adopt this integration in the future.

If you have a multi tenant situation for a Cognito User Pool you should also consider using multiple pools since that is the only way to fully separate tenants (you’ll always need overall  unique email address eg, in most cases).